# How to set connection pool to 100 in sql server 2005 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-pooling

How to set connection pool to 100 in sql server 2005 instance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to change it, you need to do this on the client, as Remus already mentioned. The client is creating the connection pool.

You can specify the connection pooling properties in your connection string that you use to connect to SQL Server. The most important properties are:

- **Pooling** : which can be true or false - use pooling or not
- **MinPoolSize** : minimum size of connection pool; default is 10
- **MaxPoolSize** : maximum size of connection pool; default is 100

So if you want to enable pooling and have min. 20, max. 250 connections, you could use this connection string:

```
server=MyServer;database=MyDatabase;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=25;Max Pool Size=250
```

For more details, see the MSDN docs or check out the [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) web site.

Marc

Comment: +1 for patience :) Interstingly enough, the connection settings are documented for SMO, but not for SqlClient, which I find odd. (SMO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionsettings.maxpoolsize.aspx)

Comment: should be `Min Pool Size=25;Max Pool Size=250` (with spaces)

Comment: @Magnus: thanks for pointing that out - you're 100% correct - updated my post

Answer (score 1):

[Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) is a client setting and is already at 100 per appdomain:

> Connections are added to the pool as
>   needed, up to the maximum pool size
>   specified (100 is the default).